# Add enabling Relative Line Number to init.el

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In Emacs 26.x, How do I get Emacs to start with Relative Line Numbers turned on by default ?

I tried to use `C-x h`, then clicked the menu item and the help showed the following

```
<menu-bar> <options> <showhide> <display-line-numbers> <relative> 
runs the command #[nil "\300\301!\210\302\303!\207"
[menu-bar-display-line-numbers-mode relative message "Relative line
numbers enabled"] 2 nil nil] (found in global-map), which is an
interactive compiled Lisp function.
```

So tried adding the command into init.el as

```
(menu-bar-display-line-numbers-mode relative message "Relative line
numbers enabled")
```

How do I make this work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, Emacs's help message is pretty bad in this case.  The menu button is bound to an anonymous function, and the help system is basically displaying the byte-compiled version of that function.  I got the Emacs source, searched for the unique looking string "Relative line numbers enabled", and found the function in lisp/menu-bar.el:

```
   (lambda ()
     (interactive)
     (menu-bar-display-line-numbers-mode 'relative)
     (message "Relative line numbers enabled"))
```

So you can use `menu-bar-display-line-numbers-mode`, which takes only one argument, to set it:

```
(menu-bar-display-line-numbers-mode 'relative)
```

---

The canonical way to set this is adding `display-line-numbers-mode` to a mode hook,

```
(add-hook 'foo-mode-hook #'display-line-numbers-mode)
```

or enabling `global-display-line-numbers-mode` if you want them everywhere,

```
(global-display-line-numbers-mode 1)
```

and to set `display-line-numbers-type` to the desired style:

```
(setq display-line-numbers-type 'relative)
```

Comment: Thanks. Any suggestion where to find better emacs help in a forum?

Comment: You want *better* help than jpkotta just provided?!

Comment: Oh, did you misinterpret the sentence "Unfortunately, Emacs's help is pretty bad here." as meaning that **Stack Overflow** wasn't very good at providing help for Emacs?  @jpkotta was saying that the help provided by Emacs itself -- when you used `C-h k` -- was poor in this instance (which was on account of the key being bound to an anonymous function).  Stack Overflow contains a ton of *excellent* help for Emacs questions.  There is also https://emacs.stackexchange.com/ (which is a newer member of the network).

Comment: @Ozzz I can see that being misinterpreted, I changed it.  Stackoverflow and Emacs stackexchange provide excellent help.  Also, I'd recommend filing a bug report to at least add docstrings to those functions.